# Assigning 1D arrays to a 2D array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am looking for ways to implement the following functionality in my VBA macro. I have an 2D array of size (xx,yy) that I want to dynamically fill. The problem is that the function returning values returns 1D arrays. with reversed size (yy, 1) instead of (1,yy). Is there a way to dynamically assign next rows using arrays returned by the fuction. The pseudo-code implementing the functionality is below:

```
Dim X() As Double
ReDim X(1 to xx, 1 to yy)
Dim i As Long

For i=1 To xx
     X(i,)= FunctionReturningArrayOfSize(1 to yy, 1 to 1)
Next i
```

EDIT: Just to make clear - every row of my resulting array X is returned by a execution of FunctionReturningArrayOfSize (in a for loop).

Comment: No, there is no way to assign part of array to another array other than For loop. Are you trying to repeat the `FunctionReturningArrayOfSize` array `xx` times?

Comment: Yes, I want to repeat it xx times, returning and an (yy,1) array each time. As a result i want to have an (xx,yy) array.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Excel, so you can use the `Transpose` function from VBA.

Transpose will automatically convert a 1D array to 2D array.

```
Sub Test()

  Dim a1D() As Variant
  'Assign a 1D array
  a1D = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

  Dim a2D As Variant
  'Transpose to a 2D array
  a2D = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a1D)

End Sub
```

Comment: I wanted exactly what the OP wanted, but transpose just converts a 1D row to a 2D column array with multiple rows and one column. Plz suggest a way out by using loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign 1D array to 2D `Range` but not to part of another array.

```
Dim X() ' has to be Variant array
With Range("A1").Resize(xx, yy)
     .Value2 = FunctionReturningArrayOfSize(1 to yy, 1 to 1)
     X = .Value2    ' or X = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Value2) to rotate it
End With
```

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate a for loop with this approach?

Comment: @Max The point of this example is that it will repeat the yy values of FunctionReturningArrayOfSize xx times without any loops. Do you want a For loop example by rows, columns, or cells?